# QuickBlox create user issue (bad request) without any error message

Tags: quickblox

I want to create an user using the rest API. Rest API returns an error (bad request), when I made the request. There are not any other error messages.

JSON:

Required Parameters : login, password, email

http://quickblox.com/developers/Users#API_User_Sign_Up

```
{
 "user":
   {
    "login":"user123456",
    "password":"User11@2015",
    "email":"xxx@ccc.com.tr",
    "blob_id":null,
    "external_user_id":null,
    "facebook_id":null,
    "twitter_id":null,
    "full_name":null,
    "phone":null,
    "website":null,
    "custom_data":null,
    "tag_list":null
  }
}
```

**Rest API Result:**

> Response Status Code : BadRequest.
>
> Response Content is empty. No error message.

I do not understand the error. Can you help me?

**Code :**

```
 public NotificationUser CreateUser(string token, NotificationUser notificationUser)
    {
        var user = new QuickbloxUser()
        {
            email = notificationUser.Email,
            password = notificationUser.Password,
            login = notificationUser.Login

        };
        var jsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
        var request = new RestRequest("users.json", Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("QB-Token", token);
        request.AddParameter("user", jsonBody);

        var response = _restClient.Execute<RootUser<QuickbloxUserResponse>>(request);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            notificationUser.Id = response.Data.user.id;
            notificationUser.Email = response.Data.user.email;
            notificationUser.Login = response.Data.user.login;
            return notificationUser;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code/curl you are using? Remember to hide your token though.

Comment: I added the sample code.